# Bing Custom Search - Stopped Working

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

Bing Customer Search has stopped returning results in many cases today. We received an email that was a quota warning, however, we were informed the quota was 20,000 where the email says 1,000.

The pricing page also still says that quota is 20,000 for the preview.

Is there a general problem with the service or an issue with the quota system?

We don't want to have to move services again.

Answer (score 0):

It was throwing a 403 quota error. Then a night later it was no longer doing so. This was probably a bad cloud update and was fixed by Microsoft.